# ntfs-3g poor write speed

Tags: ubuntu, performance, ntfs

I'm getting very bad write speeds with ntfs

`sudo mount -t ntfs -o sync,noatime,gid=users /dev/sdf1 "/media/MNTPNT"`

testing with DD

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/6ED8C60456B3EBDA/test.tmp bs=1k count=128k`

```
2585+0 records in
2585+0 records out
2647040 bytes (2.6 MB) copied, 22.6904 s, 117 kB/s
```

This is to a 1tb WD Passport, I also have a 500gb WD Passport formatted with ext4 which (last logged run of rsync) averaged writes at 15MB/s

`sudo cat /dev/sdb | pv -r > /dev/null`

Gave read speeds ~40MB/s

Linux 3.0.0-12-server   21/11/11        _x86_64_        (2 CPU)

Comment: Have you tried different block sizes instead of 1k?  Perhaps 4k maybe?

Comment: What is the physical interface? USB?

Comment: bs=4k did boost write to 1.5MB/s, yes interface is USB, will test the ext4 drive again to see max write

Answer (score 3):

Try `bs=32k`, `bs=64k`, or even `bs=1M`: USB has significant turnaround time - and you use sync mount option. That kills write speed as it disables the write cache.

Comment: interesting, removed `sync` & `noatime` and now writing at ~40MB/s with bs=4k. rsync averaged ~26MB/s

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the parameter *big_writes* into your mount command:

sudo mount -t ntfs -o async,big_writes,noatime,gid=users /dev/sdf1 "/media/MNTPNT"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was with `sync` option, the default is to mount everything with `async`. Synchronous operations take more time than asynchronous by definition. So, you can put back `noatime` and actually you can get some performance gain from it but I am not sure if `noatime` has any effect on ntfs-3g.